# How to command ffmpeg to output metadata received on stream

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, rtsp

I use ffmpeg to receive an RTSP stream from a security camera. There are 3 sub-streams from the camera:

```
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 2592x1944 [SAR 1887:1888 DAR 629:472], 15 fps, 100 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp
  Stream #0:2: Data: none
```

I've handled the audio and video fine, but haven't figured out how to handle the Data. This data contains motion alarms, faults, and other data. I used the following map option to specify the data source:

```
-map 0:2
```

But I cannot find an output format that it will accept.

Comment: The mpeg-ts container accepts a data stream. Try `-f mpegts outfile`

Comment: @Alain1A45 Thanks for the help.  I've used your suggestion and cut down the ffmpeg options to only those for this substream and now I'm getting something.  Thanks so much.

Comment: To read the data, you can try something like : `ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:2 -c copy -f data metadata.txt`

Comment: @Alain1A45 Perfect.  I've been looking through the ffmpeg documentation for some time, but never read that section on muxers.  You've been a tremendous help.  Now, how do we get you credit for answering the question?  If  you put your last comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To record your camera streams, you can use the mpeg-ts container which accepts data streams.
To record in an mpeg-ts container:
`ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts record.ts`
And then to read / to extract the data content:
`ffmpeg -i record.ts -map 0:2 -c copy -f data data.txt`